# Beamer: framed box for frame title

Tags: beamer, framed, box

I prepared the following source

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=Green!10}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Brown,bg=Yellow!20}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=DarkBlue}

\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}

Bla bla

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image]

I would like to modify a bit the yellow box of the frame title to be framed. I tried using the command `\setbeamertemplate` but unsuccessfully. It is probably something quite easy, and there are some tips in other topics, but I have not find a way and I'm probably too dumb with beamer! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=Green!10}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Brown,bg=Yellow!20}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=DarkBlue}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Yellow!20,coltext=Brown,enlarge left by=-\beamer@leftmargin,width=\paperwidth]
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}

Bla bla

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. It is quite the think I had in mind, but the frame box should cover completely the page. I would modify your answer myself, but I have not completely understood it yet.

Comment: @Logos please see my edited answer

Comment: now it's much better. Can you just remove the rounded corners?

Comment: @Logos Have a look at the documentation of the tcolorbox package

Comment: Okie dokie, thank you very much. I didn't know the package `tcolorbox` I will study its documentation.

Comment: @Logos You can adjust the appearance of the box by changing the line `\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Yellow!20,coltext=Brown,enlarge left by=-\beamer@leftmargin,width=\paperwidth]`